# Why orderby in ICollection gives System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[Object,System.DateTime]? How can I get list/collection of object back?

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating a collection of Reservatie and ordering it based on DateTime in Controller. In Test class I am asking it back but I get key-value pair? back. Why is it giving OrderedEnumerable and how can I get collection back?

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Index(Gebruiker gebruiker)
{
    ICollection<Reservatie> reservatielijst = gebruiker.Reservaties;
    if (reservatielijst.Count == 0)
    {
        return View("leeg");
    }
    return View(reservatielijst.OrderBy(r => r.StartDatum));
 }
```

Test class method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexGeeftAlleReservatiesVoorHuidigeGebruiker()
{
    //Arrange
    Reservatie reservatie = new ReservatieImp();
    Reservatie reservatie1 = new ReservatieImp();
    student.Reservaties.Add(reservatie);
    student.Reservaties.Add(reservatie1);

    //Act
    ViewResult result = controller.Index(student) as ViewResult;
    var r1 = (IOrderedEnumerable < Reservatie, DateTime > ) result.Model;


    //Assert
    //Assert.AreEqual(2, reservaties.Count);
}
```

Error that I get is:

```
Test Name:  IndexGeeftAlleReservatiesVoorHuidigeGebruiker
Test FullName:  DidactischeLeermiddelen.Tests.Controllers.ReservatieControllerTest.IndexGeeftAlleReservatiesVoorHuidigeGebruiker
Test Source:    C:\Users\Suresh SUBEDI\Projecten II 2015 - 2016\groep22DotNet\DidactischeLeermiddelen.Tests\Controllers\ReservatieControllerTest.cs : line 44
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.3139783

Result StackTrace:  at DidactischeLeermiddelen.Tests.Controllers.ReservatieControllerTest.IndexGeeftAlleReservatiesVoorHuidigeGebruiker() in C:\Users\Suresh SUBEDI\Projecten II 2015 - 2016\groep22DotNet\DidactischeLeermiddelen.Tests\Controllers\ReservatieControllerTest.cs:line 53
Result Message: 
Test method DidactischeLeermiddelen.Tests.Controllers.ReservatieControllerTest.IndexGeeftAlleReservatiesVoorHuidigeGebruiker threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[DidactischeLeermiddelen.Models.Domain.Reservatie,System.DateTime]' to type 'DidactischeLeermiddelen.Tests.Controllers.IOrderedEnumerable`2[DidactischeLeermiddelen.Models.Domain.Reservatie,System.DateTime]'.
```

[image: datatype]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error it appears that you have defined your own `IOrderedEnumerable<T,U>` interface.  `OrderBy` returns a class which implements the `IOrderedEnumerable<TEntity>` interface from Linq; it has no knowledge of your custom interface, so there's no way that the result can be cast to it.

You can just cast to `IEnumerable<Reservatie>` to access Linq extension methods:

```
var r1 = result.Model as IEnuerable<Reservatie>;
```

Comment: Yes I made IOrderedEnumerable<T,U> interface in test class itself in order to be able to cast it. I was still unable to cast. I don't need IOrderedEnumerable<T,U> but Model is always returned as OrderedEnumerable with or without IOrderedEnumerable. I am trying to access nr of Reservatie in Model. with var I can't call count or list or anything.

Comment: @SureshSubedi OK I see where I went wrong.  The type of `ViewResult.Model` model is just object so you can't call linq methods on it directly.  You should be able to cast it to an `IEnumerable<Reservatie>` though.

Comment: I wasn't able to cast it to ICollection<Reservatie> either. But that solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Because it's not an `ICollection<T>`.  `OrderBy` returns a iterator that returns the items in the specified order.

Answer (score 1):

`(IOrderedEnumerable < Reservatie, DateTime > )` is wrong you get `IOrderedEnumerable<Reservatie>` ordered by date(StartDatum), in other words, the collection is the same just sorted sorted by StartDatum. Just cast your model to `IOrderedEnumerable<Reservatie>`

Comment: The type of Model is OrderedEnumerable<Reservatie, DateTime>. I was trying to cast it to IOrderedEnumerable but was unable to do so. I just need count of Reservatie in Model.

Comment: @SureshSubedi But when you call `OrderBy` you get a _different_ class back, which does not implement your custom interface.

Comment: Ok I'll remove (IOrderedEnumerable < Reservatie, DateTime > ). But How can I get count of Reservaties in Model or r1?

Comment: directly on the result just result.Model.Count()

Comment: can't call Count Model is returned as object. Also model IS returned as OrderedEnumerable<Reservatie, DateTime>. Thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: Casting to IOrderedEnumerable<Reservatie> worked as well.